# "Params specify an EIP-1559 transaction but the current network does not support EIP-1559"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am working on a decentralized application project. Whenever I am trying to do any write operation on smart contract from my react application I am getting this error. Smart Contract is fine, fully functional on remixIDE. reading operation is working fine.

Tired different version of web3.js and metamask(both upgrade and downgrade). Switched back and forth between the Ethereum main network and another network. Changed but did not work.

[image]